# mamba upgrade to 1.x

Tags: version, upgrade, mamba

I have mamba 0.27 installed on my mac OS.
How can I upgrade to mamba 1.x?

Can I simply do a fresh re-installation of the newer version, if I want to keep my existing mamba environments and settings?

I checked mamba's documentation, and I searched in internet, but could not find any "how to upgrade" information.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mamba is like any other package in a Conda environment and can be updated like:

```bash
mamba update -n base mamba
```

If that doesn't update (perhaps due to needing dependencies updated), another option is to use a minimum version:

```bash
mamba install -n base 'mamba>=1'
```

Please note the use of quotations to avoid the `>` being interpreted writing to a file called "`=1`".

Comment: I've excluded the specific environment (-n base), and I was able to upgrade. Independent of any mamba environment it has now upgraded to the newer version. `mamba update mamba`

Comment: Installing the `conda` or `mamba` package in anywhere other than **base** will lead to surprising behavior - do not do that. E.g., it leads to creating `pkgs/` and `envs/` directories *within* the environment.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! It would have been better if they had avoided executing those update/install commands, but it is good to know!